# Read each line of a .txt file into an array in bash/shell/unix in Mac OS X without readarray or mapfile commands

Tags: arrays, bash, macos, shell, unix

I am working on a simple catalog program for my personal library in bash/shell. I am developing in OS X and am stuck on how I am supposed to configure my program without access to UNIX commands such as `readarray` or `mapfile`.

Here is the logic of what I am trying to do:

- init my program by reading a series of config files that contain the various attributes books that have been cataloged during a previous session. I want the information of each .txt file (one entry per line, per book) read and indexed into an array  (ex. titles.txt -> TITLES=(), authors.txt -> AUTHORS=(), ect...)
- Once the arrays have been filled with the cataloged info, I want to input the attributes of a new book into the catalog by appending the new information to each respective array. This new content would be pushed into the arrays after a confirmation prompt such as "are you sure this information is correct, if yes it will be saved to catlog, if no it will be discarded"
- after the new book attributes have been successfully added to the respective arrays, I want to update/save the updated arrays into to the same .txt config files i used to init the program, appending the newest information to the bottom of each file

Here is what I wanted to do with `mapfile`

```
init_catalog(){
    #read catalog entries into arrays
    printf "%s\n" "Loading catalog..."
    mapfile -t TITLES < titles.txt
    mapfile -t AUTHORS < authors.txt
    mapfile -t EDITORS < editors.txt
    mapfile -t PUB_NAMES < pub-names.txt
    mapfile -t PUB_LOCATIONS < pub-locations.txt
    mapfile -t PUB_DATES < pub-dates.txt
    mapfile -t PAGE_COUNTS < page-counts.txt
    mapfile -t GENRES < genres.txt
    mapfile -t ISBN_NUMS < isbn-nums.txt
    printf "%s\n" "Catalog loaded..."
    INITIALIZED="true"
}

save_catalog_entry(){
    clear
    printf "%s\n\n" "You have entered the following information for this work:"
    printf "%s\n" "PENDING ENTRIES FOR THIS WORK..."
    underline_above_text
    printf "Title: $WORK_TITLE\n"
    printf "Author(s): $WORK_AUTHOR\n"
    printf "Editor(s): $WORK_EDITOR\n"
    printf "Publisher: $WORK_PUB_NAME\n"
    printf "Publication Location: $WORK_PUB_LOCATION\n"
    printf "Publication Date: $WORK_PUB_DATE\n"
    printf "Page Count: $WORK_PAGE_COUNT\n"
    printf "Genre: $WORK_GENRE\n\n"
    underline_above_text
    printf "%s\n" "Is this information correct? If yes, all pending entries for this work will be saved to catalog. If no, all pending entries for this work will be discarded."
    yes_or_no
    if [ $USER_INPUT_YES_NO == "true" ]
    then
        #save input to catalog files
        printf "%s\n" "${TITLES[@]}" > titles.txt
        printf "%s\n" "${AUTHORS[@]}" > authors.txt
        printf "%s\n" "${EDITORS[@]}" > editors.txt
        printf "%s\n" "${PUB_NAMES[@]}" > pub-names.txt
        printf "%s\n" "${PUB_LOCATIONS[@]}" > pub-locations.txt
        printf "%s\n" "${PUB_DATES[@]}" > pub-dates.txt
        printf "%s\n" "${PAGE_COUNTS[@]}" > page-counts.txt
        printf "%s\n" "${GENRES[@]}" > genres.txt
        printf "%s\n" "${ISBN_NUMS[@]}" > isbn-nums.txt
    else
        DISCARDING_ENTRIES="true"
        printf "%s\n" "All input information for this work has been discarded. Please, try again."
    fi
}
```

Does anyone know which UNIX commands I should/can use to access these config files from the shell, read their contents into arrays, and then save the new content of the arrays back into the .txt config files? Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the normal array construction methods (`arr[n]="asdas"` and `arr=( "123" 45 "ss gg" )`). Consider this titles.txt file:

```
once upon a time
pink "cherry" troubles
obfuscator 2
```

Just read it into a variable by either using bash's `f=$(<filename)` construct (older than `mapfile`, so you should have it) or other tools like `cat`. Then you can iterate over it in a `while read` loop and save the lines to an array. If you don't need the variable, you can also just read the file in the loop (`...; done < filename`). Saving back would be done in a similar manner, just looping over the array instead and either using `>>` to append individually or redirecting the whole loop, where you can use a normal empty-and-fill `>`.

**Approach 2**
To skip the explicit loop, read the file to an array by splitting it into whitespace separated pieces first:

```
oifs=$IFS # save a copy of the input field separator character list
IFS=$'\n' arr=( $(< titles.txt) )
IFS=$oifs # restore
$ echo "${arr[@]}"
once upon a time pink "cherry" troubles obfuscator 2
$ echo "${arr[1]}"
pink "cherry" troubles
```

Or if you want to also mark the titles' boundaries more obviously, you can quote them:

```
oifs=$IFS
IFS=$'\n' arr=( $(sed -n 's,",\\",g; s,^.*$,"&",p' titles.txt) )
IFS=$oifs
$ echo "${arr[@]}"
"once upon a time" "pink \"cherry\" troubles" "obfuscator 2"
$ echo "${arr[1]}"
"pink \"cherry\" troubles"
```

Comment: your solution don't work if lines contain phrases with spaces. It will make each word into an array element, what goes against your own example.